# When network path changes under your feet: svn doesn't work

Tags: svn

I have a SVN repository and a checked out version both on a Machine I Don't Manage[tm]. The sysadmin did some background work on paths/mountings and my work is effectively hijacked at the moment. This is in Red Hat Linux. I know on Windows, SmartSVN has an option where you can retarget the source repository to deal with situations like this.

How do I set the new repository path in the checked out version?

Comment: Are you using a file:// url, or a svn:// or http:// url for your repository?

Comment: file:// as it turns out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "svn switch --relocate". Look all the way at the bottom of this link for how to deal with your problem.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html

Comment: probably needs to look at the --relocate option, to be more specific.